# Installing node.js and npm on Windows IoT core

Tags: pi-2, windows-iot, node.js

I have a Pi 2, (Model B) with Windows 10 installed on it. I would like to write a simple program according to this [tutorial](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/12/09/windows-iot-core-and-azure-iot-hub-putting-the-i-in-iot/#VAmrRwyIuJJmQIYi.97).

In the tutorial there are some npm configurations, where they write that I need to make sure I have node.js installed. Now, I am not sure that I need to install node.js and npm on my Pi. (Maybe I am misunderstanding). But, if I do - how do I do it? I couldn't find any instructions, and it's not like I have a web browser on my Pi.

P.S - I am VERY new to the whole Pi/IoT stuff, so please be gentle with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js consists of two parts, the server side and the package manager (npm)

When working with node in visual studio, you typically use npm to install node packages, that are bundled with your project and deployed to the Pi IoT as a .NET application.

A node server, can also be deployed to the Pi, by adding the correct nuget package into your project.

You can install Node on a server and let the application download dependencies as it needs it but with Windows IoT you need to bundle the Node dependencies with the project, build and deploy it.

It also depends on the type of application you start of with and also you can mix and match project types - But deployment becomes a bit more complicated.

- https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/05/12/bringing-node-js-to-windows-10-iot-core/#K8bZwv5IwhHcAhhz.97
- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/helloworldnode
- http://www.opentechguides.com/tutorials/nodejs/8/windows-iot-installation.html